# Data loading in Oracle APEX

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I create pages for loading data from CSV through Data Load Wizard. CSV-file contains data not for all fields, but this fields are required.

How can I insert data in fields, that not contains in CSV, for example, using queries to another tables?

My APEX vervion is 4.1.1.00.23

Comment: When does the data need to be present, as in does it all have to be inserted at once to satisfy constraints on the table? You have the option of default values/triggers/or @rajesh-chamarthi's suggestion of MERGE.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using Oracle SQL.

If there is a unique ID for the table that you are loading into (let's say you have most of the employee in a csv), you can use that ID to merge or update data from other tables.

For a table like this...

```
empid,
ename,
zip_code
state_code
```

Example : you can load this using CSV

```
EMP:

empid,
ename,
zip_code
```

and then update the state using this query.

```
update emp tgt
   set state = (select state
                  from zip_code_lookup src
                  where src.zip_code = tgt.zip_code
               );
```

If there is more than one column that needs to be updated, I prefer using the merge command.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_9016.htm#SQLRF01606

Answer (score 0):

you can refer to this link for more information about data loading to multiple tables using the data loading wizard http://vincentdeelen.blogspot.in/2014/03/data-load-for-multiple-tables.html

Comment: Link only answers are frowned upon on SO due to link rot. What happens if the link dies? At the very least, perhaps you can answer the question with some of the details that the link provides.